# Get cached external properties file from Spring MVC app running on tomcat6

Tags: java, spring-mvc, vim, ubuntu-12.04, tomcat6

I have web Spring MVC application running on tomcat6 and Ubuntu 12.04. App requires .properties file which is located in {home}/config/some.properties. I've cleaned this file my mistake (on running tomcat) via Vim and closed it. So no .swp file left. I think tomcat should have cached this file or properties of this file. I need to get them.

P.S. I haven't stopped tomcat since needed properties file existed.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have Vim 7.3 / 7.4 and `:set undofile?`. Then, at least parts of it may be in the persistent undo file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have :set undofile config.

Comment: So, that's what backups are for. Or try out some undelete utilities (depending on the underlying file system type); first step would be to create an image of the whole disk to avoid overriding anything.